# How to access my NAS via the command line using rsync

Tags: command-line, samba, rsync

I have always been accessing my NAS (dlink-343) via the gui in Caja or Nautilus. The connection says `smb://dlink-15gtac`.

How can I access my NAS via the command line if I want to copy files to there, for example, using `rsync`.

According to the admin panel in my NAS, it says the workgroup is `netstar` and name is `dlink-15gtac`.

I've tried a bunch of different ways but, I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Type the following command:

```
route
```

This should give you something like:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Then type the command:

```
telnet TheIPAddressBelowTheWordGateway
```

It should then ask you for a user name and password.  Give it the username and password *of the router*

This should bring you to a Linux shell *on your router*. You can then issue any command that your router's Linux firmware has installed.

**Warning** I don't own your hardware, so cannot test this for you...

Comment: ... and do what exactly?

Comment: they you're in the (linux) command-line of the D-Link...  if rsync is installed, (I don't have your hardware) you can just run it... Probiere mal! ;-)

Comment: I am certain you can do better - its not me having the problem.

Comment: @guntbert: Besser???  :P ;-)